# Nant and satellite assemblies

Tags: nant, satellite-assembly

Am looking for a Nant sample with satellite assemblies.
I googled now for hours without success.

I got this far:

```xml
<resgen todir="${build}">
  <resources>
     <include name="${src}/Resources/*.resx" />
  </resources>
</resgen>
```

and the csc subelement:

```xml
<resources prefix="Resources">
  <include name="${build}/ResourceManagement.resources" />            
</resources>
```

But how do I do create the satellite assemblies? When I try to include non neutral resources I get a strange error (for example ResourceManagement.de.resources:

```
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeCompatibilityAttribute' from assembly 'myassembly'
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I will answer my question, maybe there is a better solution:

I did not find a nant task to create satellite assemblies. However, you can create one with **al** task.

```
<al output="${build}/de/myassembly.resources.dll" 
          target="lib"
          culture="de-CH">

         <sources>
            <include name="${build}/Resources.ResourceManagement.de.resources" />            
         </sources>        

</al>
```

Since I did not find out how to set the namespace for the resourcefile, I just renamed it:

```
<move file="${build}/ResourceManagement.de.resources"
               tofile="${build}/YourNamespace.ResourceManagement.de.resources"
               overwrite="true"/>
```